# How to open post Show page in a modal with Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog, ruby-on-rails-5

My homepage displays a list of posts and when I click a post, it open as a new page,

but I need to stay at the homepage and open post Show page as modal. Any idea how?

Thank you

Comment: Probably the most efficient way to do this is to use AJAX.  You would send an AJAX request to the server and then take the results and use it to populate a modal.  If you only have a few posts on a page, you could simply render all of the modals on one page and then use javascript to hide and show them as appropriate.

Comment: hmm, thanks for the direction, I will research about AJAX then. I have hundreds of items.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solution is with the assumption that you are using bootstrap...

change your show action for js requests

```
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

add this div at the end of posts index

```
<div id='post-content'></div>
```

your link to show page must look something like this now

```
  <%= link_to 'View Post', post_path(post), remote: true %>
```

add a new file posts/show.js.erb

```
$('#post-content').html("<%= j render 'post_modal', post: @post %>");
$('#post-modal').modal('show');
```

add a partial posts/_post_modal.html.erb

```
<div id="post-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <div>
         --- put all your show.html.erb code here 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I'm not using Bootstrap, I will still try to solve from your way. Thank you

Comment: wow! it actually worked! Thank you! I'm studying your approach to learn better now. Thank you! Btw do you have any suggestion on how can I keep the URL, so that it can be shared? Currently I get error https://i.imgur.com/9wjw720.png

Comment: it seems like you have missed remote: true in your link_to tag <%= link_to 'View Post', post_path(post), remote: true %>

Comment: happy to help..!

Comment: Thanks again mate! I actually have the remote:true btw  `<%= link_to image_tag(post.image_url.to_s), post_path(post), remote: true %>`

Comment: its difficult for me to find the problem without looking at the code, please create a sample project on Github and push your code there (if you may).

Comment: hmmm, I don't use GitHub. ‍♂️ btw removing    `respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end` solved the issue. Now the show link works great, and modal still works  I just need to apply URL to address bar somehow when we view post in modal.

Comment: Thanks, is there a name for this solution?